# Identify if a network interface is a `veth` using `/sys/class/net`?

Tags: networking, veth

Is it possible to unambiguously identify that a given network interface, such as `eth1`, is actually a type `veth` network interface? Please note that in containers, their network interface names typically start with `eth*` instead of `veth*` and one cannot be sure that there's not a real `eth` in the set. Can this be detected through `/sys/class/net`?

I'm under the impression that the `iflink` element in `/sys/class/net/...` does not unambigously identify `veth` network interfaces, but instead is used in other situations as well. If there is no way to solve my question using the `/sys/class/net/...` filesystem, is there a socket call that can give me this information, preferrably usable in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>After even more research I've come to the conclusion that my goal isn't achievable using `/sys/class/net/...`.</strike> Luckily, it **is** achievable.

## Mounting the Correctly Namespace'd `/sys/class/net`

Thanks to [Danila Kiver's answer to "Switching into a network namespace does not change /sys/class/net?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457384) all I need to do is to mount `sysfs` in some place in order to get the correctly (network) namespace'd view to `sysfs` and its `class/net/` branch.

The following Python example scans for network namespaces, and then lists all network interfaces in a specific network namespace, marking each physical network interface with `[PHY]`. Please note that this script needs root/admin cap, especially due to the mount.

```
import psutil
import nsenter
from ctypes import c_char_p, c_ulong
import ctypes.util
import os
import tempfile

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/29156997
libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'), use_errno=True)
libc.mount.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_ulong, c_char_p)
libc.umount.argtypes = (c_char_p, )

netns_index = dict()
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    netns_ref = '/proc/%d/ns/net' % process.pid
    try:
        netns_id = os.stat(netns_ref).st_ino
        if netns_id not in netns_index:
            netns_index[netns_id] = netns_ref
    except PermissionError:
        pass

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_mnt:
    for netns_id, netns_ref in netns_index.items():
        with nsenter.Namespace(netns_ref, 'net'):
            print('net:[%d]' % netns_id)
            if libc.mount('sysfs'.encode('ascii'),
                          temp_mnt.encode('ascii'),
                          'sysfs'.encode('ascii'),
                          0,
                          ''.encode('ascii')) >= 0:
                for nif_name in sorted(os.listdir('%s/class/net' % temp_mnt)):
                    nif_path = os.readlink('%s/class/net/%s' % (temp_mnt, nif_name))
                    phys_nif = not nif_path.startswith('../../devices/virtual/')
                    print('  %s %s' % (nif_name, '[PHY]' if phys_nif else ''))
                libc.umount(temp_mnt.encode('ascii'))
```

## Workaround Without `/sys/class/net`

However, the NETLINK interface to the Linux kernel provides the required information, otherwise the `ip link` command wouldn't be able to tell the kind of interface.

The key here is the `IFLA_LINKINFO` attribute that is returned when asking the kernel for a list of network links (that is, network interfaces). Inside it is another attribute called `IFLA_INFO_KIND`, it is `veth` in case of an `veth` network interface, or `bridge` in case of a Linux Kernel bridge.

Please note that `IFLA_LINKINFO` is an optional attribute; for instance, the loopback, ethernet, and wifi network interfaces don't offer `IFLA_LINKINFO`.

This information can be easily gotten in Python using the famous [pyroute2](http://docs.pyroute2.org/index.html) netlink library. `pyroute2` deals with all the nasty NETLINK stuff, install it easily via `pip3`. This example simply iterates over all network interfaces visible in the current network namespace, giving their names, interface index, and the `IFLA_LINKINFO` value, if present.

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute

netw = IPRoute()
for link in netw.get_links():
    ifindex = link['index']
    ifname = link.get_attr('IFLA_IFNAME')
    linkinfo = link.get_attr('IFLA_LINKINFO')
    if linkinfo is not None:
        linktype = linkinfo.get_attr('IFLA_INFO_KIND')
    else:
        linktype = 'None'

    print('{0}: #{1} {2}'.format(ifname, ifindex, linktype))
```