# Switching into a network namespace does not change /sys/class/net?

Tags: linux, namespace, network-namespaces

The Linux man page for [network namespaces(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html) says:

> Network namespaces provide isolation of the system resources associated with networking: [...], the /sys/class/net directory, [...].

However, simply switching into a different network namespace doesn't seem to change the contents of `/sys/class/net` (see below for how to reproduce). Am I just mistaken here in thinking that the `setns()` into the *network* namespace is already sufficient? Is it always necessary to remount `/sys` in order to get the correct `/sys/class/net` matching the currently joined network namespace? Or am I missing something else here?

### Example to Reproduce

Take an *ubuntu system, find the PID of the rtkit-daemon, enter the daemon's network namespace, show its network interfaces, and then check `/sys/class/net`:

```
$ PID=`sudo lsns -t net -n -o PID,COMMAND | grep rtkit-daemon | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
$ sudo nsenter -t $PID -n
# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
# ls /sys/class/net
docker0  enp3s0  lo  lxcbr0  ...
```

Please notice that while `ip link show` correctly only shows `lo`, `/sys/class/net` shows *all* network interfaces visible in the "root" network namespace (and "root" mount namespace).

In the case of `rtkit-daemon` also entering the mount namespace of it doesn't make a difference: `sudo nsenter -t $PID -n -m` and then `ls /sys/class/net` still shows network interfaces not present in the network namespace.

## "Fix"

Many kudos to [@Danila Kiver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/297621/danila-kiver) for explaining what really is going on behind the Linux kernel scenes. Remounting `sysfs` *while* the correct network namespace is joined will show the **correct** entries in `/sys/class/net`:

```
$ PID=`sudo lsns -t net -n -o PID,COMMAND | grep rtkit-daemon | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
$ sudo nsenter -t $PID -n
# MNT=`mktemp -d`
# mount -t sysfs none $MNT
# ls $MNT/class/net/
lo
# umount $MNT
# rmdir $MNT
# exit
```

So this now yields the correct results in `/sys/class/net`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look into `man 5 sysfs`:

```
/sys/class/net
    Each  of the entries in this directory is a symbolic link representing
    one of the real or virtual networking devices that are visible in 
    the network namespace of the process that is accessing the directory.
```

So, according to this manpage, the output of `ls /sys/class/net` must depend on the network namespace of the `ls` process. But... Actual behavior does not seem to be as described in this manpage. [There is a nice kernel documentation about how it works](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/28c20cc73b9cc4288c86c2a3fc62af4087de4b19/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-tagging.txt).

Each `sysfs` mount has [a namespace tag](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/28c20cc73b9cc4288c86c2a3fc62af4087de4b19/fs/kernfs/kernfs-internal.h#L66) associated with it. This tag is set when sysfs gets mounted and [depends on the network namespace of the calling process](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/28c20cc73b9cc4288c86c2a3fc62af4087de4b19/fs/sysfs/mount.c#L35). Each sysfs entry (e.g. an entry in `/sys/class/net`) also [may have a namespace tag](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/28c20cc73b9cc4288c86c2a3fc62af4087de4b19/include/linux/kernfs.h#L145) associated with it.

When you iterate over the sysfs directory, the kernel obtains the [namespace tag of the sysfs mount](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/28c20cc73b9cc4288c86c2a3fc62af4087de4b19/fs/kernfs/dir.c#L1649), and then it iterates over the entries, [filtering out those which have different namespace tag](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/28c20cc73b9cc4288c86c2a3fc62af4087de4b19/fs/kernfs/dir.c#L1611).

So, it turns out that the results of iterating over the `/sys/class/net` depend on the network namespace of the process which initiated `/sys` mount rather than on the network namespace of the current process, thus, you must always mount `/sys` in the current network namespace (from any process belonging to this namespace) to see the correct results.

Comment: wow! I had wished for such a comprehensive answer, but didn't dare to expect it. Thank you very much!

Comment: By "...you must always mount `/sys`" does the "you" refer to the (inquiring) process trying to access `/sys/class/net` -- and not the process creating the network namespace, correct?

Comment: @TheDiveO I mean any process in the network namespace of the inquiring process (including this process itself). That seems to be enough.

Comment: @sourcejedi sure, I will change references to the specific commit.